# Замена специальных символом на числа по порядку

Tags: java, android, текст, replace

Необходим кусочек кода, который позволит заменять специальные символы на числа, которые будут идти по порядку.

**Пример:**

**Ввод:**

```
Текст#abc
Текст#abc
Текст#abc
```

**Выход:**

```
Текст#1
Текст#2
Текст#3
```

Помнится я раньше уже делал такую штуку, только вот сейчас забыл, а она нужна.. Прошу помочь)

Comment: Регулярные выражения? Найти совпадение и менять в цикле каждую группу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так ([весь код](https://www.ideone.com/VEy1FE)):

```
String text = "Текст#abc\nТекст#abc\nТекст#abc";
String toReplace = "abc";
    
int number = 1;
    
while (text.contains(toReplace)) {
    text = text.replaceFirst(toReplace, "" + number);
    number++;
}
    
System.out.println(text);
```

Консоль:

```
Текст#1
Текст#2
Текст#3
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ может чуть-чуть отличаться в зависимости где именно у вас текст, в одном месте или в разных, но принцип будет тот же:
создаем переменную, которая и будет нашим вставляемым числом, увеличивающимся при нахождении места для замены, разбиваем текст на строки, меняем и объединяем обратно.
В итоге должно получиться что-то вроде этого:

```
int num=0;
String toReplace="abc";
String[] strings=text.split(" ");
String result="";
for(String string:strings){
 num++;
 if(result.euals("")){
  result=string.replace(toReplace,num+"");
 }else{
  result+=string.replace(toReplace,num+"");
 }
}
text=replace;
```